# Dropped cases from matched studies

Tags: causality, matching, epidemiology, confounding

We have cohort data and a rare exposure which we are matching to controls in a large epidemiologic dataset. The matching variable is a deidentified neighborhood indicator (cluster) which guarantees that individuals within clusters are highly correlated. This is a social epidemiology type of analyses looking at health related outcomes and socio-behavioral "determinants" as possible risk factors with cross-sectional data (our analytic variables of interest were only collected at baseline).

After controlling for individual level confounders, we were left with the issue of neighborhood level confounders which are vast and of extreme importance. Neighborhood level information was not made available to us, so matching based on neighborhood seems like an adequate way to control for its confounding effects.

When the matching was performed, we lost 10% of cases due to unmatched pairing (small numbers or lack of controls). My question is:

1. does exclusion of unmatched cases indicate a possibility for residual confounding due to unmeasured neighborhood level confounders (despite all individuals being adequately matched in the final analysis)
2. is looking at a fixed effects model a feasible sensitivity analysis for assessing whether matching was reasonable and correct?

Comment: Is there a reason not to include all cases and fit a mixed model using neighborhood as a random effect (in lieu of pairing)? This would remove the variations among neighborhoods from the residual error. In addition, the significance of neighborhoods would indicate the importance of those variations.

Comment: Very good question. Even with the 10% reduction of sample size, we have adequate *power* to do a matched analysis. From what I know of the sample, it is very representative. The parametric assumption of normal distributions for the random effect may not adequately model the actual influence of neighborhood level determinants, and these unmeasured neighborhood level variables are *strongly* associated with exposure of interest. There are also several clusters that are extremely unbalanced in distributions of cases and controls which can lead to unstable estimation.